How can I make my python selenium script work while minimized?
I have a python script that reads input_names.csv which contains names and zip codes. Using this information the program open chrome with selenium, minimizes it, and enter the information into White Pages so it can get address and phone. Unfortunately, the program does not work after being minimized.
I have tried switching from visibility_of_element_located() to element_to_be_clickable but it still does not work.
Here is my code:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import time
import csv
import setuptools

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)

def scrape_white_pages(name, zip_code):
    global driver

    driver.get("https://www.whitepages.com/person")

    try:
        # Wait for the address input field to be present and interactable
        name_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-address"]'))
        )
        name_input.clear()  # Clear any existing text in the input field
        name_input.send_keys(name)

        # Wait for the zip code input field to be present and interactable
        zip_code_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-location"]'))
        )
        zip_code_input.clear()  # Clear any existing text in the input field
        zip_code_input.send_keys(zip_code)

        name_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        time.sleep(3)  # Adjust sleep time as needed

        # Check if owner name and phone number elements are present
        elements = driver.find_elements("class name", "faq-question")

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(elements[0])).click()
        address = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="faq-0"]'))).text.strip()
        address = address[address.index("is") + 3:address.index(".")]

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(elements[1])).click()
        phone_number = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="faq-1"]'))).text.strip()
        phone_number = phone_number[phone_number.index("is") + 3:phone_number.index(".")]

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

    return address, phone_number

def save_to_csv(data, filename='owner_info.csv'):
    with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(data)

def main():
    names = []
    zip_codes = []
    #address = input("Enter address line 1: ")
    #zip_code = input("Enter ZIP code: ")
    with open("input_names.csv", "r") as file:
        lines = csv.reader(file)
        for line in lines:
            if line != '':
                if "Name" not in line and line[0] != "":
                    names.append(line[0])
                    zip_codes.append(line[1])
        file.close()
    counter = 0
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
    driver.minimize_window()
    for i in names:
        name = names[counter]
        zip_code = zip_codes[counter]
        address, phone_number = scrape_white_pages(name, zip_code)
        if len(list(phone_number)) < 15:
            if address and phone_number:
                print(f"Address: {address}")
                print(f"Phone Number: {phone_number}")
                # Save data to CSV file
                save_to_csv([address, zip_code, phone_number, name[:name.index(" ")], name[name.index(" "):].replace(" ", "")])
            else:
                print("Address information not found.")
            counter += 1
        elif address and phone_number:
            print(f"Address: {address}")
            print(f"Phone Number: None Found")
            # Save data to CSV file
            save_to_csv([address, zip_code, "N/A", name[:name.index(" ")], name[name.index(" "):].replace(" ", "")])
        counter += 1
    driver.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()



If you don't want Selenium to be visible to the user. You can use selenium headlessly. (See Headless Browsers). You can do this by passing the following options when initializing the driver:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options)

In the following code snippet I created a lookup function that takes a name and returns the first address from whitepages. However with the "--headless" option flagged, no browser pops up.
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')


def lookup(driver: webdriver.Chrome, name: str):
    driver.get("https://www.whitepages.com/person")
    name_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="search-address"]'))
    )
    name_field.clear()
    name_field.send_keys(name)
    name_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    time.sleep(2)

    elements = driver.find_elements("class name", "faq-question")

    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(elements[0])).click()
    address = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="faq-0"]'))).text.strip()
    address = address[address.index("is") + 3:address.index(".")]

    return address

if __name__ == "__main__":
    svc = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=binary_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=svc, options=options)
    johns_address = lookup(driver, "John Smith")
    print(johns_address)

Hope that helps.

Now I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Willi\Downloads\ikoalpha-attachments\name_final.py", line 100, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\Willi\Downloads\ikoalpha-attachments\name_final.py", line 81, in main
address, phone_number = scrape_white_pages(name, zip_code)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Willi\Downloads\ikoalpha-attachments\name_final.py", line 56, in scrape_white_pages
return address, phone_number

Hey William I don't think you included the whole error message but my guess is that there's an error occurring before the address and phone_number variables are declared.
For example, its possible your search didn't yield any results and therefore elements is an empty list. I can't really tell without the rest of the error message. I would suggest using my example as a starting point and going from there. You can use print statements or the debugger to keep track of the values and make sure they are what you expect.

After Running you code I get:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Willi\Downloads\ikoalpha-attachments\name_final.py", line 39, in 
johns_address = lookup(driver, "John Smith")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Willi\Downloads\ikoalpha-attachments\name_final.py", line 19, in lookup
name_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

I don't know mate, I really need to see the actual error message, what you've sent is a snippet of the traceback. If you're still using the undetected chromedriver I'd recommend just using the default chrome driver here.

The problem with the default chrome driver is that it will be blocked by cloud flare

After looking over it more I found that the problem seem to be driver.find_elements(). Normally this would return a list of elements matching, in this case, the class name (faq-question). But when in the background it instead returns a empty list causing the program to crash.
